# Convert HTML into ADF format Jira API

Tags: php, jira, jira-rest-api

Goody Day community,
I am create an issue using Jira rest API. Here is the dacomentaion https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/platform/rest/v3/api-group-issues/#api-rest-api-3-issue-post

Everthing work fine but when I try to pass HTML in description it's show HTML tags on jira. Is there is any way I can convert HTML to ADF.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert HTML into ADF by using https://github.com/wouterken/htmltoadf this git code. I have convert my HTML into ADF using this.

Hopefully, this will help you.

Thanks